# Do genitive numerical phrases block the plural?

Tags: particle-の, plurals

Context:

> [両]{りょう}の[貴様]{きさま}は[明日]{あした}の[末]{すえ}に[亡]{な}いです。

with the intended meaning

> Both of you will be dead by the end of tomorrow.

This question is about the 「**両の貴様は**」. I understand that the "plural/collective" is not used if there is a classifier phrase indicating the number of objects preceding the object to pluralize. My problem here comes from the ever-irritating "Inverted Partitive Genitive" behavior. 両の, an adjective-like object (noun in the genitive) meaning "both of," is technically a numerical phrase qualifying 貴様は. My question is:

## Should the presence of a genitive numerical phrase prevent pluralization?

More concretely, should my sentence above begin with:

- [両]{りょう}の[貴様]{きさま}は
- [両]{りょう}の[貴様]{きさま}たちは

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 両の貴様は
>   両の貴様たちは

I'm afraid both are incorrect and make little sense. 
To say "Both of you", you could say:

> 貴様らは二人とも
>   貴様らはどちらも
>   貴様らは両方とも
>   貴様らは両方
>   etc.

---

"Both [noun]..." could be 両方のXXが, XXが両方, XXが両方とも, eg:

> 両方の手が, 手が両方, 手が両方とも, 両手が *Both hands (nom.)*
>   両方のカードを, カードを両方, カードを両方とも, カードを二枚とも *both cards (acc.)*
>   <sub>You don't need to pluralise the noun.</sub>

But "both of [pronoun]" doesn't work this way; to mean "both of you/us/them", you don't say:

> *両方のあなたたちが, *両方の私たちが, *両方の彼らが, *両方のそれらが

You'd instead say:

> あなたたち/私たち/彼らが二人とも/両方とも, それらが二つとも/両方とも

<sub>全部 and すべて ("All of ~~") work the same way; you can say 全ての人/人々が, 全ての商品が, 商品が全て, 商品を全部, りんごを３つとも etc., but 全てのあなたたちが, 全ての私たちが, 全部のそれらを sound unnatural.</sub>

---

> 両の貴様は明日の末に亡いです。

This makes little sense, I'm afraid.

> Both of you will be dead by the end of tomorrow.

could translate to something like:

> 貴様らは二人とも明日の終わりまでには死んでいるだろう。
>   貴様らは二人とも明日の終わりまでに死ぬだろう。

Comment: This helps, thank you! (Although, let me point out that the "both of you will be dead" was intended to be a statement of fact, i.e. my character is saying "Both of you will [with 100% probability] be dead by the end of tomorrow [because I will have killed you and there is no way for you to survive and I will not change my mind]." In this case is the volitional required for the **definite** future action or will the imperfective work?)

Comment: @QScience Volitional だろう is not required when the meaning is clear from the context. So, to sound more definite how about... 「貴様らは二人とも明日の終わりまでに死ぬ！」or 「～～死ぬのだ！」

Comment: @QScience ... or maybe.. 「貴様らの命も (もはや)明日までだ！」とか「貴様らは明日までの命だ！覚悟しろ！/ 覚悟するがいい！/ 覚悟するんだな！」とか・・・　it'd depend on the context, though.